# How to split Suffix from a number using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert this: `NIFTY 16th JAN 12300 CE` into `NIFTY 16<sup>th</sup> JAN 12300 CE` using jQuery?

Comment: Not sure what jQuery has to do with string manipulation. Basic regular expression will do it.

Comment: No need JQuery : `"NIFTY 16th JAN 12300 CE".replace("th", "<sup>th</sup>")`

Comment: Do you want to also substitute "rd", "nd", "st" (as in "third", "second", "first")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a regular expression. To help negate the possibility of a false positive when the target string occurs *within* a word you can have the regex look specifically for the `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th` strings when they follow an integer of 1 or 2 characters in length. Try this:

```js
["NIFTY 16th JAN 12300 CE", "rd ND 21st April"].forEach(v => {
  let output = v.replace(/(\d{1,2})(st|nd|rd|th)/gi, '$1<sup>$2</sup>');
  console.log(output);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split `th` and rejoin with `<sup>th</sup>`

```js
var x = "NIFTY 16th JAN 12300 CE";
var y = x.split("th").join("<sup>th</sup>");
console.log(y);
```

Comment: Will not work with 1st, 2nd or if NIFTY is replaced by nifthy...

Comment: How will splitting by `th` will gets effected if `NIFTY` is changed.

Comment: @AtulSharma if "NIFTY" becomes "nifthy" the result will be `"nif<sup>th</sup>y 16<sup>th</sup> JAN 12300 CE"`. That's how.

Comment: Agree, but There is nothing like `nifthy`, why would NIFTY will become nifthy.

Comment: The point being: this could be error-prone, since we don't know in what ways the string can present itself (which is not your fault, it's OP who's not being precise).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for the given requirement.

It works by identifying the day number, day suffix and replacing the pattern with required one.

```
var input = "NIFTY 16th JAN 12300 CE";

// Get the day string (Examples: 16th / 3rd)
var dayString = input.match(/[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+/g);

// Get the day-number and day-suffix
var dayNumber = dayString.toString().match(/[0-9]+/i);
var daySuffix = dayString.toString().match(/[a-zA-Z]+/i);

// Print the output
console.log(dayNumber + "<sup>" + daySuffix + "</sup>");
```